# rxjs observables lifecycle : detecting a completed observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there a way to know if an `Rx.Observable` has completed AFTER the  fact, i.e. after `onCompleted` call on the subscribers? This would be similar to the `has_next` method for iterators. I could not find anything in the doc (or elsewhere) on that subject.

For a cold observable, the question would not make so much sense, as one can resubscribe  at will, and the observable will be started anew. For a time-limited hot observable, one could imagine the edge case of being passed a reference to that hot observable, and subscribing for its values, never receiving anything and not even knowing that nothing will ever be received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from another channel (quoted below).

The "usual" channels of creating a hot observable, such as creating a subject or using `.publish()` will "replay" the terminal message (i.e., `onError` or `onCompleted`), but there is no such guarantee in general. I would argue though that any hot sequence that did not have this terminal message replay violates the contract of an observable, and appropriate bugs should be filed.

Answer (score 2):

Evers obserbable or observer have the property isStopped. This is eighter true if it is completed or error was thrown or it is false which means it it still active.